# How to iterate a firebase database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I need to iterate the users of my Firebase Database. I have a token for each user, and I want to send a notification to each user of the database.

My database looks like this:

[image: Databse]

```
console.log('Sending a notification to all users');
var ref = functions.database.ref('/users');
for (var token in ref){
    console.log('Hello from: '+ ref.token);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are getting? Do you want to access `email` or other fields of `token`?

Comment: I want to iterate the database accessing the token field so I can send a notification to each user in the database

Answer (score 1):

Your `ref` is just a reference to a specific path in Firebase Realtime Database. You haven't queried it, so you don't have anything back yet. Try this:

````js
console.log('Sending a notification to all users');
var ref = functions.database.ref('/users');

// Query the database
ref.once('value').then((usersSnapshot) => {
  // Get back all the user records and iterate through them.
  usersSnapshot.forEach((userRecordSnapshot) => {
    // I'm guessing your record id is the token?
    const token = userRecordSnapshot.key
    // To get the other values, for example
    const email = userRecordSnapshot.val().email
  });
});```
````